# add zoom and scroll capability with code behind to SCICHART

Tags: wpf, scichart

Hi I want to add zoom and scroll with code behind to SCICHART
is this possible?
I tried xaml but It did not work. My manager wants it with code behind.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this should be easy, for each modifier in SciChart WPF, you can add it in code behind like this:

```
var sciChartSurface = new SciChartSurface();
sciChartSurface.XAxis = new NumeriAxis();
sciChartSurface.YAxis = new NumeriAxis();

sciChartSurface.ChartModifiers.Add(new ZoomPanModifier());
sciChartSurface.ChartModifiers.Add(new MouseWheelZoomModifier());
sciChartSurface.ChartModifiers.Add(new ZoomExtentsModifier());
```

See a full list of the modifiers available in [SciChart WPF here](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/webframe.html#What%20is%20the%20ChartModifier%20API.html)